# issue with running git commands from java program

Tags: java, git

I am trying to run a git command through java program using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToBeExecuted);

and commandToBeExecuted ="git log" ;
```

i have set env variables but still getting the error like:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
    at GITCodeCoverage.createLog(GITCodeCoverage.java:40)
    at GITCodeCoverage.main(GITCodeCoverage.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:188)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:132)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
    ... 5 more
```

Any can please help me in this run this command succesfully on Windows system.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just so you know, this error doesn't occur on my Ubuntu machine with Git installed.

Comment: this error doesn't occur on my windows machine either .does this command work when you type manually in cmd??

Comment: yes, when i run this command from command promt it is working fine and giving the results. do i need to set any path in my eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this overloaded `Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)` like:-

```
File gitPath = new File("path where git is located in your system");
Runtime.exec('git logs', null, gitPath);
```

Comment: i tried using File gitPath=new File("C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/"); Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("git log",null,gitPath); but still geting the error message: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: can you run `git log` from your command prompt window ? and also check whether this git exists in that location or not

Comment: i have ran that through cmd and that gives me the output but i investigated and found there was a need of setting path for git under run-config in eclipse,  Thank You So much for you help.

Comment: Ok. Please update with your results once done with this. Glad that it helped